# How to dynamically parse string of array to another type?

Tags: .net

I am trying to parse a string of array to any type (int, date, double) based on the property type. however, the below code fails. Can someone please help

```
string[] test = {"30", "40"}

var finalType = GetFinalType();
var objArr = test;
var arr = Array.CreateInstance(finalType, objArr.Length);
Array.Copy(objArr, arr, objArr.Length); -- Fails because its not able to convert "30" to 30
```

Another approach i tried

```
MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.Name);
var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)member.Member).PropertyType;
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyType);

var arr = Array.ConvertAll(filter.Value, converter); // - Gives error that i have to specify the type
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the transform with a Select. This would really iterate the items one by one though.

```
var numbers = array.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

or replace the `int.parse` within with the GetFinalType() etc.

Comment: `array.Select(int.Parse).ToArray()`

Comment: I am looking to parse the array using System.Reflection, var finalType = GetFinalType(); will have the type that it has to be converted to

Comment: If i replace int.parse with Type, i get the error --> The type arguments for method 'method' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.